# How to open modal bootstrap from controller asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

```
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("SendMessage", "Home", new AjaxOptions
            {
                HttpMethod = "Post",

            }, new { @class = "form-inline", @id = "contact-for", @onsubmit = "validateForm();" }))
                {  



@* <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtWant" placeholder="I want the photographer to take pictures of......" />

                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pac-input" placeholder="Enter the location" />*@

                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email to get notified when we launch" style="width: 500px">

                    <button id="find" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Enter</button>
@*  <span style="color: white">or</span>

                    <button id="createPhotogig" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Create PhotoGig</button>*@




                }
                We won't spam your Inbox, we'll send you ONE email when we launch
            </div>
            @if (TempData["messageshow"] != null)
            { <div class="alert-success">@TempData["messageshow"]</div> }
```

How do open the `@TempData["messageshow"]` on a twitter bootstrap modal.

Please help?

Answer (score 0):

add a hidden value while in razor as if(@TempData["messagehow"]==xxx){ShowModal} then in your javascript document lodad check if($('#showmodal').text()==ShowModal) //show modal